# Perl/SNMP : get ifIndex by ifName

Tags: perl, snmp

i'm new to Perl and SNMP and i'm trying to develop an application to visualise the network for my internship.

I have a first script, given a mac address, a community and a switch's ip, can find the correspondant interfaceSpeed, ifAlias, duplex mode...

```
$perl mac-ifindex.pl -m 203B697B0438 -h 192.168.1.1 -c public  
Adresse mac : 203B697B0438 => (VLAN : 1, NumPortBridge : 25)  
Ifindex : 10101  
Vitesse : 1000  
Alias : switch-cisco-3750  
Interface name : Gi0/1  
Duplex : 3 (full)
```

For my second script, I want to give interface name, community and switch's ip to find all others informations. Which oid to get a table of ifIndex corresponding to port ? or something that could help me.

Thanks,
Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a really simple solution :

```
use Net::SNMP::Interfaces; 
my $interfaces = Net::SNMP::Interfaces->new(Hostname => $hostname, Community => $community); 
my $inter = $interfaces->interface($ifname);
```

So, I can get ifindex : `$inter->index();`
But I need to find mac address too and I don't have the VLAN.
Anyone ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to interface names, there is the standard MIB-II which has ifDescr (OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2) which contains *some* sort of unique name for each interface, as well as ifAlias (OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18) which on Cisco IOS boxes usually has a more useful device name.

Do some experimentation to find out what these MIBs look like (and what names your switch insists to use for the interfaces in the ifDescr and the ifAlias fields).  Get some tool for 'walking' the SNMP MIB trees and subtrees to explore what things look like in it.  For windows, IIRC Getif is a good MIB-browser.  If you are on a linux box (or other UNIX) I would recommend Net-SNMP, which provides a good command line tool for walking SNMP MIBs.

For perl libraries I would recommend Net::SNMP (available on CPAN), even if it is a bit heavy on various dependencies (a lot of cryptography related modules necessary to support the security features of SNMPv3) or SNMP_Session.pm+SNMP_util.pm+BER.pm (the latter three are the perl libraries MRTG (http://www.mrtg.org) relies on and they come bundled with it).  In MRTG, under the bin directory, you find the utility cfgmaker.  It is a perl script which talks a lot of SNMP to whatever network gear you point it to in order to figure out what interfaces the device has, so it's source is a good read if you want to understand how SNMP can be used with perl.

For gathering information about MIBs I can recommend MIBDepot (http://www.mibdepot.com).  Their search function is free.  If you want to download MIBs from them they require you to pay a small, reasonable amount of money (something I recommend you do, they deserve some support for their free search services).

Hope this helps!